# How can I sort a readonly datagridview

Tags: sorting, datagridview, readonly

I just don't want users to manually add/edit/delete any record in the grid. All records are added by the program dynamically. Yet i want to allow users to sort the records by clicking the column header.

Is this requirement really so contradictory that the readonly and sorting can't be achieved at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the magic is the type of the data source of the datagridview. It has to implement some specific interfaces to support certain features such as sorting.